# How to use puma in production mode by set production environment?

Tags: sinatra, rack, puma

I made a little [Sinatra app](https://github.com/markson/ORM-Server). In my Gemfile add `gem 'puma'` in the production group

```
group :production do
    gem 'puma'
    gem 'dm-postgres-adapter'
end
```

And I set production mode in `config.ru`

```
set :environment, :production
```

But after I run `backup`, the default webrick web server run instead.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use puma :)

```
$ puma config.ru
```

You can run your Sinatra application with Puma from the command line like this:

```
$ ruby app.rb -s Puma
```

Or you can configure your application to always use Puma:

```
require 'sinatra'
configure { set :server, :puma }
```

You can pass it as an option to rackup:

```
 $ rackup -s Puma
```

Alternatively, you can modify your config.ru to choose Puma by default, by adding the following as the first line:

```
 #\ -s puma
```

[More documentation on puma.](https://github.com/puma/puma)